# Why MySQL return is always 1 in C# code but not when I test in stored procedure?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am developing an ASP.net application using MySQL and have a question related to a stored procedure return value.

This is my stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`pcg`@`%` PROCEDURE `UpdatePreSellerProfile`(
IN UserID INT(11),
IN SellerImageID INT(11),
IN BusinessImageID INT(11),
OUT ProfileUpdated INT(1)
)
BEGIN
SET @Approved = 'APPROVED';
UPDATE user SET 
    SELLER_IMAGE_ID = COALESCE((SELECT IMAGE_ID FROM image_url WHERE IMAGE_USER_ID = UserID AND IMAGE_ID=SellerImageID),SELLER_IMAGE_ID),
    SELLER_BUSINESS_LOGO_ID = COALESCE((SELECT IMAGE_ID FROM image_url WHERE IMAGE_USER_ID = UserID AND IMAGE_ID=BusinessImageID),SELLER_BUSINESS_LOGO_ID)
WHERE (USER_LOGIN_ID = UserID AND USER_PROFILE_STATUS = @Approved);
SET ProfileUpdated = ROW_COUNT();
END
```

When I test this code with following MySQL script I get 0 (`@ProfileUpdated`) always when there is no update.

```sql
call UpdatePreSellerProfile(@UserID, @SellerImageID, @BusinessImageID ,@ProfileUpdated);
```

But when I check this in my C# code, it is always showing 1 (`ProfileUpdated`).

```cs
if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    MySqlCommand oCommand = new MySqlCommand("UpdatePreSellerProfile", oMySQLConnecion);
    oCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    MySqlParameter sqlProfileUpdated = new MySqlParameter("@ProfileUpdated", MySqlDbType.VarString);
    sqlProfileUpdated.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlProfileUpdated);

    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellerImageID", oSeller.SellerImageID);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessImageID", oSeller.BusinessLogoID);

    oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Int16 ProfileUpdated = Convert.ToInt16(oCommand.Parameters["@ProfileUpdated"].Value);

    if (ProfileUpdated > 0) // <<-- Should be greater only if it is updated is sucessfull
    {
        oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.SUCCESS;
        oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.SUCCESSFULLY_DATA_UPDATED);
    }
    else
    {
        oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.ERROR;
        oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.ERROR_NO_RECORDS_UPDATED);
    }
    oMySQLConnecion.Close();
}
```

Why is the difference between MySQL script vs C# code?

Comment: Is there a reason to be using an out parameter in this case? Why not just Select on row count?

Comment: I want to keep the sql script editable without recompiling ASP.net code

Comment: Why are you using `VarString` if it's an `int`?

Comment: Good catch, but the issue is the same. It should have been INt32.

Comment: @PCG It's `int(1)` too, as opposed to `int(11)`.

Comment: IN Parameters should be in INT(11). That's how they are defined in tables.

Comment: Yet the out parameter is int(1).

Comment: Yes, return should not be more than 1 at any time.

Comment: ROW_COUNT() doe snot work as intended in Visual studio and MySQL script. This is what I am trying to understand. This is working fine when I test this in MySQL script. The SAme stored procedure returns correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have set the `UseAffectedRows` connection string option, it defaults to `false`. [This means](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/):

> When `false` (default), the connection reports found rows instead of changed (affected) rows. Set to `true` to report only the number of rows actually changed by `UPDATE` or `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements.

Additionally, from the [documentation of the `ROW_COUNT` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count):

> For `UPDATE` statements, the affected-rows value by default is the number of rows actually changed. If you specify the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag to `mysql_real_connect()` when connecting to mysqld [ed. note: this is the same as `UseAffectedRows`], the affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by the `WHERE` clause.

Thus, the `UPDATE user` statement in your stored procedure will return the number of rows that were found by the query, not the number that were actually updated.

To fix this, either:

1. Set `UseAffectedRows=true;` in your connection string; this may cause changes to other `UPDATE` queries.
2. Add more conditions to the `WHERE` clause, e.g., `WHERE ... AND SELLER_IMAGE_ID != SellerImageID AND SELLER_BUSINESS_LOGO_ID != BusinessImageID`, to make sure the row is only found and updated if it actually needs to change.

Comment: Why would `UseAffectedRows` in the connection string affect `ROW_COUNT()` inside the stored procedure? Doesn't it only affect row counts of raw statements executed via the connection?

Comment: ROW_COUNT() should show the rows got updated inside Store procedure for my understanding and as per documentation. Here I don't understand why it does not report correctly in C# code but it works as intended if I do a MySQL script call.

Comment: Thank you, Bradley. I understand mostly what you are saying but my questions is why @ProfileUpdated return two values in mySQL script and C# code. ROW_COUNT works as intended inside StoredProcedure.

Comment: I did a little more debugging. If I set @ProfileUpdated=0 in-store procedure returns 0 in C# code. But otherwise always it is 1. BUt works fine in MySQL script call. So it seems that when the Stored procedure is triggered by C# code, ROW_COUNT behaves differently than Call in MySQL script.

Comment: The documentation is clear: the return value of the `ROW_COUNT` function depends on the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag presented by the client when it connects; for a C# program, this is controlled by the `UseAffectedRows` connection string option.