# Is MySQL ROW_COUNT in stored procedure works as in spec in Visual studio C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, rowcount

I have the following MySQL stored procedure :

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`pcg`@`%` PROCEDURE `UpdatePreSellerProfile`(
    IN UserID INT(11),
    IN SellerImageID INT(11),
    IN BusinessImageID INT(11),
    OUT ProfileUpdated INT(1)
    )
    BEGIN
    SET @Updated = 0;
    SET @Approved = 'APPROVED';
    UPDATE user SET 
        SELLER_IMAGE_ID = COALESCE((SELECT IMAGE_ID FROM image_url WHERE IMAGE_USER_ID = UserID AND IMAGE_ID=SellerImageID),SELLER_IMAGE_ID),
        SELLER_BUSINESS_LOGO_ID = COALESCE((SELECT IMAGE_ID FROM image_url WHERE IMAGE_USER_ID = UserID AND IMAGE_ID=BusinessImageID),SELLER_BUSINESS_LOGO_ID)
    WHERE (USER_LOGIN_ID = UserID AND USER_PROFILE_STATUS = @Approved);
    SET @Updated = ROW_COUNT();
    SET ProfileUpdated = IF (@Updated>0,1,0);
    END
```

Right after the UPDATE statement, I read the number of updated records using ROW_COUNT();. [Per spec](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count), this should return the last number of updated records in the UPDATE statement.

However, unfortunately, this is not working as I expected when triggered the stored procedure in C# code in Visual studio. 
If I trigger the stored procedure in MySQL script using C#, It always returns 1 regardless of change. 
The OUT variable "ProfileUpdated" suppose to return the updated number of records to C#, but it's always 1. When I check in MySQL script using CAll to stored procedure, it is returning as expected.

What's the best way I could get this correctly into my VS code?

Comment: *It always returns 1 regardless of change.* The value returned (in ProfileUpdated OUT variable) is set in the statement `SET @Updated = IF (ProfileUpdated>0,1,0);` - i.e. the number of affected rows  which was obtained in previous statement is successfully overwrited and, so, is lost.

Comment: Its a typo in my code. I corrected it. Issue here is that @Updated = ROW_COUNT(); is always 1 when I trigger it with C# code. But correctly works when I trigger with MySQL script.

Comment: Trigger processes only one row always. `FOR EACH ROW`...

Comment: @Akina, sorry I don't understand your comment. Why ROW_COUNT() behaves differently ?

Comment: When you tell the word "trigger" speaking about SQL the word may have only one meaning. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: I was thinking of execution. Not related to triggers in mySQL.

Comment: I've already answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59704564/23633
It depends on how the client connects, which is controlled by the `UseAffectedRows` connection string option in C#.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger, yes you are correct. I did not understand first but when I tried it worked.